# What is wrong with this thinking? Linear Algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $T \in L(V)$ such that each vector in $V$ is an eigenvector of $T$. Prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity.

I have googled the answer with my own proof and mine looked almost nothing like it.

The problem is that I do indeed know what the proofs in those links ( [this one for example](http://www.uccs.edu/~rcarlson/math513/Solns/hwk5-6.pdf)) are doing, but I have no understand *why* they are doing that.

Here is my embarrassing attempt

> Since $Iv = v$, and we know $Tv = \lambda_v v = \lambda_v Iv$

Comment: That just restates that every vector is an eigenvector. How do you show that $\lambda_v$ is the same for every $v$?

Comment: Doesn't $\lambda_v$ necessarily have to be $1$?

Comment: No, it just needs to be independent of $v$. $\lambda_v$ is a function of $v$. You have to prove it is a constant function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your proof is that you treat $v$ like it has an inverse, so you conclude that

$$Tv = \lambda_v {\rm I} v \quad / v^{-1} \quad \Rightarrow \quad T = \lambda_v {\rm I}.$$

But, vectors do not have the inverse (unless they are of order $1$, i.e., just numbers), so you cannot do that.

I won't give you the proper proof, since you say you got that.

Comment: But all I am doing is showing that $Tv = $ some multiple of $Iv$. I never considered the inverse in my thinking. How could it have arise?

Comment: You've shown (in fact, you were given) that, for each $v$,  $Tv$ is some multiple of $Iv$, but that's not the same as saying $T$ is a multiple of $I$.  The former allows different multipliers $\lambda_v$ for different $v$'s; the latter requires that there be one single multiplier $\lambda$ that satisfies $T=\lambda I$ and therefore works for all $v$'s.

Comment: @sidth Exactly, you have that $Tv$ is a multiple of ${\rm I}v = v$, which is a definition of an eigenvector. So, how do you get from that to $T = \lambda{\rm I}$ for some $\lambda$? Every matrix $A$ has an eigenvector, i.e., a vector $w$ such that $Aw$ is a multiple of $w = {\rm I}w$, but not every matrix is a multiple of ${\rm I}$.

Comment: @sidht More generally, if you have $Ax = Bx$ for $A,B,x$ anything (numbers, matrices, vectors,...), you can conclude that $A = B$ only if $x$ has an inverse and you postmultiply (right-multiply) with it. Otherwise (i.e., $x = 0$, or $x$ is a singular matrix, or...), such conclusion cannot be made. It **may** still be true that $A = B$, but it may also not be the case.

Comment: @sidht Try to give mathematically correct argument why are you allowed to remove $v$ in $Tv = \lambda_v {\rm I} v$, without using the inverse of $v$. Note that $\lambda_v$ is dependent of $v$, so you cannot just say "because it holds for all $v$", because it's a different $\lambda_v$, hence a different equation, for different vectors $v$. This is what Andreas was writing about in his comment. Of course, in the end all $\lambda_v$ turn to be equal, but at this point we don't know that. Once we do, the statement is practically proven.

Comment: Regarding ur second comment. The question says "$T$ is **a** scalar multiple" not **the** scalar mutiple

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Of course it's "a", when ${\rm I}$ has infinitely many multiples; not just one (which would be "the").

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, then the **$\lambda$-eigenspace** of $T\in {\cal L} (V)$ is the subspace $V_{\lambda}\subseteq V$ defined by $V_{\lambda}=\{v\in V:Tv=\lambda v\}$.

*Hints*:

**(1)** $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity $\iff$ $V=V_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.

**(2)** If $\lambda\neq \mu$, and if $v_{\lambda}\in V_{\lambda}$, $v_{\mu}\in V_{\mu}$, then for each $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\nu\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\alpha v_{\lambda}+\beta v_{\mu}\in V_{\nu}$.

I hope this helps!