# If $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$, then does $A=\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When my professor started teaching eigenvectors and eigenvalues the other day, the very first thing I noticed was the fact that $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$ (assuming that the equation is satisfied under the given variables) implies that $A=\lambda$... But given that A is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, how can a matrix equal a real number? What is the consequence of this?

Comment: I noticed was the fact that $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$ (assuming that the equation is satisfied under the given variables) implies that $A=\lambda$ <br>
This isn't true.

Comment: @GitGud Can you elaborate as to why?

Comment: Equation $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$ is really $$A\cdot_1\vec{v}=\lambda\cdot_2\vec{v},$$
where $\cdot_1$ is matrix multiplication, and $\cdot_2$ is scalar multiplication, two _different_ operations.

Comment: because you have $A\vec{v}$, not $\vec{v}A$

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=1\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and obviously, (as you yourself noted), $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\neq 1$.

Comment: $\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&2\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right) =2\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: The equation $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$ does NOT imply $A  = \lambda$. You can't divide by a vector. Moreover, as noted in a previous comment, the multiplications have different meaning on the two sides of this equation.

Comment: @GitGud Well - I'm sure this is more coincidence than anything, but 1 is similar to $I$ in the respect that it is the multiplicative identity... so if the matrix cannot equal a number, is there a relationship at all between the matrix and that number $\lambda$?

Comment: @agent154 If you don't like my example, take the one given by Josué.

Comment: @agent154 It's no coincidence. It's because, despite being two different operations, both operations are multiplication operations. $1$ and $I$ are the multiplicative identities of each respective multiplication operation.

Comment: But if $Av = \lambda v$ for all $v$, then $A = \lambda I$, and multiplication by $A$ is the same as multiplication by $\lambda$. In a sense, $A = \lambda$. (Don't take it too seriosuly ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, you cannot infer that $A=\lambda$ because not only are they different types of variables (matrix vs. scalar), but different types of multiplications were used.

---

As a side note, the "cancellation" rule:

> If $x \cdot z = y \cdot z$, then $x=y$.

holds true if $z$ has a multiplicative inverse $z^{-1}$ so that:
$$ \begin{array}{rrl}
&x \cdot z &=& y \cdot z \\
\implies& x \cdot z \cdot z^{-1} &=& y \cdot z \cdot z^{-1} \\
\implies& x&=&y
\end{array} $$

Note that we can't apply this cancellation rule since $\vec{v}$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse (using either matrix multiplication or scalar multiplication).

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question, but it's really important on a theoretical level that cancellative operations need not have inverses. For example, you can cancel when doing addition with natural numbers, even though the inverses (the negative integers) aren't in the set of natural numbers.

Comment: I thing you're digressing a little here: to start with, as it has been pointed out, $Av=\lambda v$ involves **two different kinds of operations** in each side of the equality. The LHS involves matrix multiplication and the RHS involves an *action*: scalar multiplication.

Comment: I don't think this is beyond the scope of the question because it's by not understanding the cancelation rule that someone could possibly ask this question.

Comment: @Adriano: you mean sufficient but not necessary? (integral domains don't have multiplicative inverses in general, but cancellation still holds)

Comment: @Kris >.< You're right. The existence of a multiplicative inverse is a sufficient but not necessary condition for applying the cancellation rule.

Comment: @GitGud, agreed. Fundamentally, this is a question about the cancellation law.

Answer (score 4):

This is an unfortunate misconception stemming from using matrix *multiplication* to model the action of a linear *function*.  Linear maps are functions, and as such, it should be clearer that to talk about $A(v) = \lambda v \implies A = \lambda$ is no more sensical than saying $\sin(\theta) = 2\theta \implies \sin = 2$.

Comment: A bit rough... somewhat too much a caricature of the situation. Linear would be better.

Comment: On the other hand, as functions $L_1(v)=Av$ and $L_2(v)=\lambda v$ are equal if their domain is taken to be the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $v$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first observation is that $A$ and $\lambda$ are of different type: $A$ is a matrix, while $\lambda$ is a scalar. However, it's easy to "fix" that be noting that for any vector $\vec v$, $I\vec v=\vec v$ where $I$ is the $n\times n$ unit matrix. This gives us a natural mapping $\lambda\mapsto\lambda I$. So we can reformulate the question:

Does $A\vec v = \lambda I\vec v$ imply $A=\lambda I$?

Well, using the vector space properties and the linearity of the multiplication, we can reformulate yet another time, by bringing both terms on the same side and factoring out $\vec v$:

Does $(A - \lambda I)\vec v = 0$ imply $\vec v=0$?

Since we can add $\lambda I$ to any matrix $X$ we like, and then of course will find that subtracting it again recovers $X$, we can simplify this question further to:

Does $X\vec v=0$ imply $X=0$?

Now remember that one way to construct a matrix is to take a vector $\vec w$ and calculate the "outer product" $\vec w\vec w^T$. If $\vec w\ne0$, then $\vec w\vec w^T\ne 0$. Now assume that there exists a $\vec w$ which is orthogonal to $\vec v$, that is, $\vec w^T\vec v=0$. Then by multiplication with $w$ you get $\vec w\vec w^Tv=0$. But that means $X=\vec w\vec w^T$ is a non-zero matrix with $X\vec v=0$.

In other words, if there exist orthogonal vectors to $v$, then from $X\vec v=0$ it does not follow that $X=0$. But orthogonal vectors exist in any vector space of dimension larger than $1$.

So if we collect all the bits together, the answer is:

If the dimension of the vector space is larger than $1$, $A\vec v = \lambda\vec v$ does *not* imply $A = \lambda I$.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not - a matrix of size larger than 1 cannot equal a scalar.  However - the eigenvalue-eigenvector relationship says that for *special vectors*, called eigenvectors, the matrix $A$ will *act like scalar multiplication* - i.e. for eigenvectors, the act of multiplying that vector by the matrix $A$ will yield the same result as if we multiplied the vector by the scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: And usually $1\times 1$ matrices aren't scalars either.

Comment: @GitGud True, technically speaking.  But they act on _all_ vectors just as the scalar does (i.e. every vector is an eigenvector of a $1\times 1$ matrix).

Answer (score 1):

We simplify things when we are thinking about scalar operations and simply cross things from one side to the other like (for example):

> $ 4x = 4(3w -1) $

the 4's on each side are cancelled out and the expression becomes:

> $x = 3w -1 $

But we are actually doing the real operations of:

> $ 4x = 4(3w -1) $
>
> $ 4^{-1} 4x = 4^{-1} 4(3w -1) \iff \frac{1}{4}  4x = \frac{1}{4} 4(3w -1)  \iff x = 3w -1  $

What you want to do in your case is:

> $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v} \iff A\vec{v}\vec{v}^{-1}=\lambda\vec{v}\vec{v}^{-1}$

But the inverse of a vector is not defined because such a definition of an inverse would have limited use, since:

> $\vec{v}\vec{v}^{-1} \ne \vec{v}^{-1}\vec{v}$

For example (as they would have different dimensions, and so on..).

Comment: Good explication, although the non-invertibility wouldn't necessarily follow from remarks about rows and columns... that's only one possible route. But your cautionary advice is good.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}, \quad v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \lambda = 5.$$

Then,

$$Av = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix} = 5 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda v,$$

even though $A \ne \lambda$.

As for the reason of confusion, this is the same problem that I have explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/453190/78926): vectors do not have inverses, which you need in order to get from $A v = \lambda v$ to $A = \lambda$. Just like $2x = 2y$ means that $x = y$ because $2$ has an inverse (so you multiply both sides by $2^{-1}$), while $0x = 0y$ **doesn't** mean that $x = y$, because $0$ doesn't have an inverse.